Unity 2D Character Animation Stuck While Moving
Why is my character floating in the air instead of standing on the ground in Unity?
I'm working on a Unity project and have implemented a character with a Rigidbody and Collider for physics interactions. However, I noticed that my character is floating or hanging in the air instead of standing properly on the ground.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 5f; // Walking speed
    public float runSpeedMultiplier = 1.5f; // Running speed multiplier
    public float jumpImpulse = 10f; // Jump force

    private Vector2 moveInput; // Movement input
    private Rigidbody2D rb; // Rigidbody2D component
    private Animator animator; // Animator component
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; // SpriteRenderer component

    public LayerMask groundLayer; // Ground detection layer
    private bool isGrounded = false; // Is the player grounded?

    public float CurrentMoveSpeed => IsRunning ? walkSpeed * runSpeedMultiplier : walkSpeed; // Current movement speed
    private bool IsRunning => Keyboard.current != null && Keyboard.current.shiftKey.isPressed; // Check if Shift is pressed

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CheckGrounded(); // Update grounded state
        UpdateAnimations(); // Update animations
        UpdateSpriteDirection(); // Update sprite direction based on movement
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ApplyMovement(); // Apply movement based on input
    }

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        // Read movement input
        if (context.performed || context.started)
        {
            moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        }
        else if (context.canceled)
        {
            moveInput = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

    public void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        // Jump if grounded
        if (context.started && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpImpulse); // Apply jump force
            animator.SetTrigger("jump"); // Trigger jump animation
        }
    }

    private void CheckGrounded()
    {
        // Ground detection using OverlapCircle
        Vector2 groundCheckPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f);
        float checkRadius = 0.2f; // Slightly larger radius for consistent detection
        Collider2D groundCheck = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPosition, checkRadius, groundLayer);
        isGrounded = groundCheck != null;

        // Debug visualization
        Debug.DrawRay(groundCheckPosition, Vector2.down * 0.1f, isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red);

        // Reset falling/jumping states when grounded
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyMovement()
    {
        // Apply movement with current speed
        Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * CurrentMoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = targetVelocity;
    }

    private void UpdateAnimations()
    {
        // Handle jump and fall animations
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            animator.SetFloat("yVelocity", rb.velocity.y); // Track y velocity for transitions
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", rb.velocity.y < -0.1f); // Falling if downward velocity
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", rb.velocity.y > 0.1f); // Jumping if upward velocity
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }

        // Handle running and movement animations
        animator.SetBool("isMoving", Mathf.Abs(moveInput.x) > 0.1f); // Ignore very small movements
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", IsRunning);
    }

    private void UpdateSpriteDirection()
    {
        // Flip sprite based on movement direction
        if (moveInput.x != 0)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = moveInput.x < 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Visualize the ground detection radius in the scene view
        Gizmos.color = isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.5f), 0.2f);
    }
}


Are you sure the animator isn't maybe overwriting some property like the Y position?

Here's a few possibilities that I can think of with the limited info:
1.
In your Animator, you most likely have multiple states, each one for each state of your character. If you simply have a delay in your character going from falling to idle, then it's possible that you have exit time on your transitions, which is causing it to have delay between states. You should do this for every transition in your animator graph. Example (The arrow properties in image should be, respectively, false, and zero.
2.
Ensure you have a transition going from each state and back, not just one way. It's pretty simple to make a small mistake with a large graph like the player's animations, so double check that you have a transition back from falling to grounded.
3.
Debug your isGrounded boolean. Perhaps it's just not actually working correctly, and it's gone unnoticed? Simply Debug.Log(isGrounded); will do the trick.
4.
Alternatively, if none of these work, please expand on your issues, what is exactly happening, is the isGrounded variable working correctly? Are you stuck in falling, and what does your animator graph look like?

Hello Timmy can i take you discord account because i can ask my question better there

idle → Walk/Run:
If isMoving == true and isRunning == false, transition to Walk animation.
If isRunning == true, transition to Run animation.
Walk → Idle:
If isMoving == false, return to Idle animation.
Run → Walk:
If isRunning == false, switch back to Walk animation.
Any State → Jump:
If isJumping == true, switch to Jump animation.
Jump → Fall:
If yVelocity < 0, transition to Fall animation.
Fall → Land:
If isGrounded == true, a short Land animation is played.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
